# useEffect triggered after onClick event - with different results

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create a dropdown menu, which shows itself and hides on hovering, and disappears after clicking its item. I thought I found a way to do it  - but it works only sometimes. (Or maybe it doesn't work - but sometimes it does.) Details below:

1. I gotta **DropdownMenu2** component, which `display` is being toggled by `onMouseEnter/Leave` events. This component (my dropdown menu) holds inside `<NavLink>` menu items.
2. I wanted the dropdown menu to disappear after clicking on menu item, so inside `<Navlink>` I created `onClick` event which triggers `handleClick`. This functions sets a `click` variable - to a CSS `className` with `display:none`. `click` is then passed to `<div>` that contains the Dropdown menu.
3. To toggle the dropdown menu `display` again on mouse hover, I had to get rid of the `click` class from the `div`. For that I created `useEffect` hook, with `click` dependency - so it fires every time `click` state changes. And function inside this hook  - changes `click` value, so it no longer represents the CSS `display:none` class.  So after (2.) - `div` containing dropdown menu has `display:none`, disapears, and `useEffect` erases that - making it hover ready.

problem:

this works only sometimes - sometimes `useEffect` is triggered so fast after `onClick`, that the dropdown menu doesn't even drop. ( `click` changes so fast that `div` container gets the "erasing" class immediately after `display:none` class )

**NaviMainButtonDrop2**

```
import DropdownMenu2 from "./DropdownMenu2";
import useHoverButton from "./sub-components/useHoverButton";

const NaviMainButtonDrop2 = () => {

  const { disp, hoverOn, hoverOff } = useHoverButton();

  return (
    <li 
      className={`nav-main__button dropdown-us`} 
    >
        <a 
          className="hover-pointer"
          onMouseEnter={hoverOn}
          onMouseLeave={hoverOff}
          >
            title
          </a>
        { disp && <DropdownMenu2 /> }
    </li>
  )
}
export default NaviMainButtonDrop2
```

**useHoverButton** (custom hook for **NaviMainButtonDrop2**)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useHoverButton = () => {

    const [disp, setDisp] = useState(false);   
    const hoverOn = () => setDisp(true)
    const hoverOff = () => setDisp(false)


  return { disp, hoverOn, hoverOff }
}
export default useHoverButton
```

**DropdownMenu2**

```
import "./DropdownMenu.css"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuItemContentSchool } from "./sub-components/MenuItemContentSchool"
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useAddClass from "./sub-components/useAddClass";

const DropdownMenu2 = () => {

  const { click, setClick, handleClick } = useAddClass("hide-menu");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[usEffect]")
    setClick("");
  }, [click]);

  return (
    <div className={`dropdown-holder-us ${click}`}>
      {/* here menu unfolds */}
    {MenuItemContentSchool.map((item) => {
      return (
        <NavLink
            to={item.link} 
            className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "d-content-us active-style" : 'd-content-us')}
            onClick={handleClick}  
            key={item.id} 
        >
          {item.title}
        </NavLink> 
      )
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
export default DropdownMenu2
```

**useAddClass** (custom hook for **DropdownMenu2**)

```
import { useState } from "react"

const useAddClass = (className) => {

    const [click, setClick] = useState("");
    const handleClick = () => setClick(className); 
    
  return { click , handleClick }
}
export default useAddClass
```

Comment: You need to decide after which event or state change you want to restore/reset your click state to empty string. What you are doing is setting click state onClick to a class and setting again to empty string immediately after render. This doesn't make any sense. What you could do, for example. is using disp value to decide when to reset your click state.

Comment: no idea how to use `disp` , as it is set after hover, and I need a function after `onClick` event (after hover)

Comment: In DropdownMenu2, change your useEffect for, useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[usEffect]")
 If(disp)  setClick("");
  }, [disp]);

Comment: So everytime you hover title, your click class will be reseted and visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are not able to get the latest state whenever you update the next state that is why it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

According to me there could be 2 solutions to this, either use a `setTimeout` or get the latest state when setting the state.

1. `setTimeout` solution-

```
 useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      setClick("")
    },2000)
```

2. Try and always get the latest state when you update the next state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[usEffect]")
    setClick((clickLatest) => "");
  }, [click]);
```

and

```
const handleClick = () => setClick((clickLatest) => className);
```

This callback will help the `useState` wait for the latest state and then update the state further.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found a simple solution to this. I don't understand why `useEffect` seems to work in a random timing, but using `setTimeOut` inside it, and delaying the execution of `setClick` - seems to do the job.

```
 useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      setClick("")
    },2000)
```